# CakePHP 3: Global variable in beforeRender() overwriting others variables in JSON view

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I'm using CakePHP 3.3.9. Well, my problem is: when I send an ajax get request to the action it does not work. I'm using "prefix route". I've found a lot of posts about how to handle Ajax in CakePHP 3, but in my case nothing is working!

**Here's my code:**

```
// routes.php

Router::extensions('json');
...
Router::prefix('myagendas', function ($routes) {
 $routes->connect('/agendas', ['controller' => 'agendas', 'action' => 'test']);
 $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);  
});
```

.

```
// AppController.php  

$this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
```

.

```
// AgendasAppController.php  

namespace App\Controller\Agendas;  
use App\Controller\AppController;
use Cake\Event\Event;  

class AgendasAppController extends AppController {
    // there's no code here yet.. I'm just extending the AppController that has all the configs..
}
```

.

```
// AgendasController.php  
...Extending AgendasAppController.php...

public function test() {                
    $test = 'not ok';
    if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
        $test = 'ok';
    }

    $this->set(compact('test', $test));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['test']);
}
```

.

```
// scripts.js  

$('#btnAdd').click(function () {        
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: './myagendas/agendas/test', //myagenda is a prefix
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(jqXHR);
        }
    });
});
```

I'm getting this error in JS console:

```
Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function config() on a non-object in AppController.php
```

**UPDATE:**
I found the error!
In my AppController in beforeRender() I'm setting a global variable checking if the user is logged in. The problem is: when I receive the data in Ajax it's not possible to get the varibles from the request, because the global variable in beforeRender is overwriting the others variables when I access the .json extension.
.

```
// AppController.php
if ($this->request->session()->read('Auth.User.role') == 'admin') {
            $this->set('loggedIn', true);
            $this->set('_serialize', ['loggedIn']);
        } else {
            $this->set('loggedIn', false);
            $this->set('_serialize', ['loggedIn']);
        }
```

**WHAT I NEED:**
Now I need to find a way to access the .json extension from view and get the global variable + the others variables from the view.  The global variable should not overwrite the others varibles.

Thanks!

Comment: Whenever receiving errors, please always post **the _complete_ error**, that is, **including the _full_ stacktrace** (ideally copied from the logs where it is available in a properly readable fashion), even if the problem might be obvious to people who are familiar with CakePHP!

Comment: @ndm That's the only error that appears in log console. It appears two times and that's it. I really don't know what's going on.

Comment: All errors in CakePHP are being logged including a stacktrace (given that the `Error.trace` option is enabled, which is the default in the CakePHP app template), also all PHP errors do show a full file path and a line number.

Comment: @ndm Problem updated! Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the variable 'loggedIn' in AppController is using '_serialize' and overwriting the others variables because it is global in beforeRender() method. I just needed to set a normal variable without '_serialize' and now it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably doing something wrong Here:

```
class AgendasAppController extends AppController {
// there's no code here yet.. I'm just extending the AppController that has      all the configs..
}
```

Should be something like:

```
class AgendasController extends AppController {

}
```

Comment: change your url to './myagendas/agendas/test.json' and check if($this->request->is("get")) instead of ajax in controller;

Comment: Still not working beacause the global variables in AppController, beforeRender() method, is overwriting the access to the other variables from the page.